# Apache solr: separate cores or group by

Tags: solr

We're implementing a product catalogue that will provide a view on *products* and *ranges*. Products consist out of multiple *items*, ranges consist out of multiple products. We would like to use solr to provide a free text search through these products and ranges, in which also item properties can be matched (e.g. a product/range with red, blue and yellow items will be matched against a 'red' query). It is important that next to the targeted products or ranges, also the ids of the items that caused the match are returned.

We currently have one core 'items' on which we perform group-by queries to obtain the resulting products/ranges (each of these items know their corresponding product and range). Is this a good practice? Or should we instead create two separate 'products' and 'ranges' cores?